# Excel 2010 VBA Macro making excel freeze

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I have a big block of data >50 across and >1500 down and some of the entries are very large negative numbers like -1000000 or -9820000 and I want all of those to be turned into -100's.
I also want any non-zero numbers that are above -100 to show 2 decimals.
I thought this vba macro would work, but its causing excel to freeze and the excel screen turns all grey and idk whats happening.
I think it might be because there are so many cells, so it takes a long time and over loads something, is there any way to make this code more efficient??

```
Sub Blah()
    For ColNum = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("1:1"))
        For RowNum = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
            If Cells(RowNum, ColNum) < -101 Then Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = -100
            If Cells(RowNum, ColNum) <> 0 And Cells(RowNum, ColNum).Value > -100 Then Cells(RowNum, ColNum).NumberFormat = "0.00"
        Next RowNum
    Next ColNum
End Sub
```

Comment: you are testing 3 times `Cells(RowNum, ColNum)` but could do it with only once by using one more Long variable (much faster), and instead of two `if` , could use `elseif` at the second one, and delete the part after `and` .  Also, declare variables (as Long). use `application.enableevents=false` end screenupdating=false, as a start. see my example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Tmdean pointed out the solution,  I'll post a sample code which might be of help.

**Edit1:** It seems assigning negative value in cell took a while as well. So apply the same principle. Get the relevant cells first and assign value in one go.

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, nonzero As Range, s As Range

    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For Each c In r
        Select Case True
        Case c.Value <= -101
            '~~> Identify the cells first and combine all of them, don't assign value
            If s Is Nothing Then Set s = c _
            Else Set s = Union(s, c)
        Case c.Value <> 0 And c.Value > -100
            '~~> Identify the cells first and combine all of them, do not format
            If nonzero Is Nothing Then Set nonzero = c _
            Else Set nonzero = Union(nonzero, c)
        End Select
    Next
    '~~> Once you got all the cells, assign value in one go
    If Not s Is Nothing Then s.Value = -100
    '~~> Once you got all the cells, format in one go
    If Not nonzero Is Nothing Then nonzero.NumberFormat = "0.00"
End Sub
```

You can replace this with your *For Loop*, whatever is easier.
You can also be more explicit on setting the *Range Object* instead or using *UsedRange.* HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in that code that's particularly slow. How many cells are you changing? The only suggestion I have is to set the NumberFormat for the entire range beforehand (to 0.00), then turn set it back to General only for the cells that are 0 or -100 in your loop. Changing the NumberFormat is probably the most expensive operation, so you want to minimize the times you set it for individual cells.

Someone will be here shortly to recommend you turn off Application.ScreenUpdating.

Comment: @rivudey Tmdean is right. Determine the cells that meets the conditions first and then format in one go. Applying format repeatedly really take a lot of time.